# Storing the Latitude and longitude values in Mysql Geomfromtext Point format using yii2 insert query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to store the Latitude and longitude values in Mysql Geomfromtext Point format using yii2 insert query.

```
 $column_name->NORTHING_EASTING = POINT(43.005895,-71.013202);
```

But it is not working.It throws some error.I dont know how to store the coordinates in mysql in point format.My field datatype is POINT(Geomfromtext).I am trying this for the past 7 days,bt i din get any idea.Pls help me out if anybody have an idea to solve this.Thanks in advance!!

I am storing the values in database as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the above code.But i am not getting the correct result.So i used simple code to solve this.

```
 $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
 $command = $connection->createCommand('INSER INTO tbl_name(NORTHING_EASTING) VALUES(POINT(43.005895,-71.013202))');
 $command->execute();
```